# Calculating syntactic complexity of a prolog predicate

Tags: prolog

Currently working on an exercise where, given some predicate, the syntactic complexity has to be calculated. The syntactic complexity of some predicate is calculated as follows:

- If the predicate is atomic or a function, its complexity is 2.
- If the predicate is a variable, its complexity is 1.

For example, the syntactic complexity of `loyalty(father(bob, Y), X)` is worked out as follows:

```
loyalty = 2 (function)
father = 2 (function)
bob = 2 (atom)
Y = 1 (variable)
X = 1 (variable)

Total = 8
```

The approach taken was calculating such complexity if the predicate was in the form of a nested list, i.e. `loyalty(father(bob, Y), X) = [loyalty, father, bob, Y, X]`, as follows:

```
complexity([], 0).
complexity([H|L], C) :- atomic(H), complexity(L, C1), C is C1+2.
complexity([H|L], C) :- var(H), complexity(L, C1), C is C1+1.
```

The remaining issue is converting the predicate to a flat list, as shown above. The `..=` is useful, but its output is not complete, that is:

```
loyalty(father(bob, Y), X) ..= ["loyalty", "father(bob, Y)", "X"]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must apply `=..` recursively as follows:

```
% term_to_list(+Term, -List)

  term_to_list(Term, [Term]) :- var(Term), !.
  term_to_list(Term, [Term]) :- atomic(Term), !.
  term_to_list(Term, List) :-
      compound(Term),
      Term =.. Components,
      maplist(term_to_list, Components, ListOfLists),
      flatten(ListOfLists, List).
```

Example:

```
?- term_to_list(loyalty(father(bob, Y), X), L).
L = [loyalty, father, bob, Y, X].
```

Alternatively, you can define `complexity/2` as follows:

```
% complexity(+Term, -Complexity)
  
  complexity(Term, 1) :- var(Term), !.
  complexity(Term, 2) :- atomic(Term), !.
  complexity(Term, Complexity) :-
      compound(Term),
      Term =.. Components,
      maplist(complexity, Components, Complexities),
      sum_list(Complexities, Complexity).
```

Example:

```
?- complexity(loyalty(father(bob, Y), X), L).
L = 8.
```

**Remark** SWI-Prolog defines `maplist/3` and `sum_list/2` as follows:

```
maplist(Goal, List1, List2) :-
    maplist_(List1, List2, Goal).

maplist_([], [], _).
maplist_([Elem1|Tail1], [Elem2|Tail2], Goal) :-
    call(Goal, Elem1, Elem2),
    maplist_(Tail1, Tail2, Goal).

sum_list(Xs, Sum) :-
    sum_list(Xs, 0, Sum).

sum_list([], Sum, Sum).
sum_list([X|Xs], Sum0, Sum) :-
    Sum1 is Sum0 + X,
    sum_list(Xs, Sum1, Sum).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Are there alternatives to the `maplist` and `sumlist` functions, as I do not believe they are available with the version of Prolog that I am using?

Comment: @drew181 See **Remark** section in my answer.